# Angular - How to execute a script stored in a string with InnerHtml

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript

I'm trying to display an html and execute a script which are both stored in a string.

I have created a pipe which transform the string with the this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml() method.

Then, I inject the content of the string in the innerHtml attribute and combine it with my pipe.

You can execute it on stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uilj36

This is a part of my code :

safe.pipe.ts

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public html = '<div>Html content</div> <script>console.log("run js ok");</script>';
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<h1>Code injection :</h1>
<div [innerHtml]="html | safe"></div>
```

The problem is that the script doesn't execute.

Anybody have an idea why the script is not executed ?

PS : I know that it's not recommended but someone asked me to do it :)

Comment: Hello. I am not sure if this is helping you, but you could you renderer and create a script element and append it to the DOM. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vqfew

Comment: The script is not executed because it is sanitized to prevent script injection. This solution is, AFAIK, not possible without parsing the string and creating the elements manually (as suggested by the comment above)

Comment: Yes !
I tested and it works. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: @MullisS Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an iFrame instead of a div element. On the iFrame you can set the srcdoc property.

```
<iframe [srcdoc]="html | safe"></iframe>
```

it should display and run the html with its scripts.If you want to restrict the iframe you can use the sandbox property.

For your example it could look like this:

```
<iframe [srcdoc]="html | safe" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

iframes are made for such security things like executing scripts in an isolated environment.